# Forcing deletion of file. Python, Windows

Tags: python, windows, file, delete-file

I am working on a Reset button. The button is supposed to clear the text that is generated in a Text Widget and delete the file that the data was being written to. Clearing the Text Widget works, but **I am having problems deleting the file**.

When I try to delete it from windows, it says that it is still open in Python. So, I closed it from my code first, and then tried to delete it but didn't work.

I have programmed the other button so that it doesn't override files. So, I can't just delete the data that is already written in the file.

Is there any way that I can force the deletion of that file??

I am using Python 2.6.6.

This is my code on the reset button:

```
    def reset_it(self):
        self.run.update() # run is the other button, I have to stop it's processing!
        self.Outputlines.update() # Forcing the TextWidget to update.
        self.Outputlines.config(state=NORMAL) 
        self.Outputlines.delete(1.0, END) # Clearing everything from the TextWidget.
        self.Outputlines.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.run.wait_variable() # Stopping the run button.

        self.infile.close() # Closing the file.
        os.remove(self.filename.get()) # Code to delete the file.
```

Comment: I don't know what polling is. Please explain?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't have a good feeling about this either. I might have to change the code in my other button :(

Comment: Is the value of `self.infile.closed == True` after you attempt `self.infile.close()` ?